# SQL query to arrange marks of students in descending order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table called `student` in a SQL Server 2000 table, to store marks of students in different subjects and it looks like

```
name | English | Math | Science
--------------------------------
Ram  | 80      | 70   | 85
shyam| 70      | 80   | 65
Hari | 80      | 60   | 90
```

Now I want the result in 3 columns with name, subject and marks and the marks column in descending order according to the subject of each student as

```
name  | Subject | marks
------------------------
Ram   | Science | 85
Ram   | english | 80
Ram   | math    | 70
shyam | math    | 80
shyam | english | 70
shyam | Science | 65
Hari  | Science | 90
Hari  | english | 80
Hari  | math    | 60
```

I tried a lot but no success. So I seek help. Thank you

Comment: pls post your attempt.

Comment: Which mark do you want in descending order?

Comment: marks of subjects in descending order

Comment: "MySQL" does not mean "the SQL code I am trying to run." If you're using SQL Server, please don't tag with MySQL or other non-SQL Server platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can uppivot your table this way

```
SELECT name,
       subject,
       CASE subject
       WHEN 'english' THEN english
       WHEN 'math'    THEN math
       WHEN 'science' THEN science
       END marks
  FROM student s CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'english' subject UNION ALL
  SELECT 'math' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'science'
) t
 ORDER BY name, marks DESC
```

Output:

```
|  NAME | SUBJECT | MARKS |
|-------|---------|-------|
|  Hari | science |    90 |
|  Hari | english |    80 |
|  Hari |    math |    60 |
|   Ram | science |    85 |
|   Ram | english |    80 |
|   Ram |    math |    70 |
| shyam |    math |    80 |
| shyam | english |    70 |
| shyam | science |    65 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a98de/1)** demo

Comment: +1 for the performance thought! Also, there is no need to UNION ALL on t subquery as there is no duplicates :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks :) On the contrary `UNION ALL` is **exactly** what needed here to prevent the attempt to deduplicate entries which is completely unnecessary step.

Comment: Did it help after all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, grad as subject, mark
  FROM
      (
      SELECT name, english as mark, 'english' as grad FROM student
      UNION
      SELECT name, math, 'math' FROM student
      UNION
      SELECT name, nepali, 'nepali' FROM student
      ) as t
ORDER BY name, mark DESC
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17dd2/3

But keep in mind that you have a bad design on your table. You should have a table with students and anoter table with grads (math, english, etc) and another one which would be a N-m relationship between those two with the mark.

Comment: Why `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? Also this gets messy if there are 5, 12, 36 courses etc. - the number of scans that have to happen alone...

Comment: Because UNION does a distinc and as the grad field garantee that it will never be equals registries there is no need to UNION ALL which doesn't do a DISTINCT

Comment: And about messy part, you are right. Thats why I suggest that the OPs design is bad.